# Should I use associative arrays in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, associative-array

I'm a student and new to Angular, so I apologize if this is obvious.

I see Angular used frequently for displaying lots of *data*.  From what I've seen, it works fantastically when your data is stored **as an array**, but only puts up a fight when you try to use it with an **associative array** (Possible, but requires work-arounds).

### Scenario:

I've got an array of kittens:

```
var kittens = [
  {
    id: "id0",
    breed: "persian",
    name: "Mr. Cuddles"
  },
  {
      id: "id1",
    breed: "siamese",
    name: "Puddin' Face"
  },
  {
    id: "id2",
    breed: "ragamuffin",
    name: "Rumblemuffins"
  }
];
```

And there are **a lot of kittens**.  I have an angular factory `kittenService` that retrieves this data from an API and maintains this array.  I need the ability to look up these kittens by id *and* filter by `breed`.  I turned this into an associative array with `id` as the key, but then I run into issues with `$filter`, etc.  There isn't as much documentation for associative arrays, and it all seems just  *easier to implement* using regular arrays.

### tl;dr

If AngularJS is used to act on data, Why are associative arrays not as common in AngularJS applications?  Should I think differently about data storage when using Angular?

Comment: wouldn't your api / database be quicker at doing the query and delivering the already filtered data to the client?

Comment: @adrichman Unfortunately, this filtering needs to be done client-side.  Filtering is used only a little bit for views, and mostly for front-end javascript behind the scenes.

Comment: They're called "objects"; JavaScript doesn't technically have "associative arrays", although they act pretty much the same in this case.

Comment: @Blazemonger I know they're at least _similar_ constructs, but you're saying that the notation `kittens["id0"]` (if I wrote `kittens` as an associative array) would be equivalent to kittens.id0 (if I were to rewrite `kittens` as an object)?

Comment: *There are no* "associative arrays", just objects. And yes, those syntaxes are equivalent in JS. Try it yourself.

Comment: @Blazemonger Do you think Angular optimizes array reference for filtering when arrays are bound to the scope? In short, does Angular handle time efficiency when I give it an array for binding?

Comment: You cannot refer to (what you are calling but in reality are objects aka hashes) associative arrays by index and you cannot do things like check the length property. My guess is it is much more efficient to work on actual arrays than to pretend that object hashes are arrays.

Comment: @MikeCheel Thanks for the input! Could you put that in an answer?

Comment: To answer your question about optimization: Probably.

Comment: How many kittens are we talking? Could your API return an array and a hash as an index? Like {"id0": 0, "id1": 1, ...}? You'd take a bigger hit up-front downloading the data but you could get the best of both worlds when searching/filtering. Or you could construct the index in the frontend and then make a search by ID wait until the index is finished.

Comment: @CarsonMyers That isn't a bad idea, although I've decided to leave further optimization for when it is needed.  The API sends an `id` field (a guid) with every entry, which I made a filter on. This isn't in production yet, but I expect several hundred kittens.  The bigger issue is that it will be making lots and lots of lookups.

Comment: Eh, a few hundred kittens probably isn't anything to worry yourself over

Comment: @CarsonMyers "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." I will wait for it to become a problem. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to (what you are calling an array but in reality are objects aka hashes) associative arrays by index and you cannot do things like check the length property. My guess is it is much more efficient to work on actual arrays than to pretend that object hashes are arrays.